# Which boolean evaluation is the fastest between <>0 and >0?

Tags: c#, performance, boolean

Let x be an integer greater or equal to 0. Action must be taken if x is greater than 0.

```cs
if (x > 0)
{
    DoSomething();
}
```

Because of the value range of x, the `if` condition can be written as `x != 0` or `x > 0`.
As this piece of code is included in a brute force algorithm, performance is critical. Which of this two conditions is the fastest to evaluate?

Comment: Did you read [this](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)? It mostly suggests that you could benchmark it yourself. Also note that the compiled code will probably be the same in the particular case of `x > 0` vs `x != 0` because of the way integers are stored.

Comment: Why don´t you just run a test over say 100 billion times, and mean it?

Comment: You can use [Benchmark.Net](https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet) to run the performance benchmarking tests.